# How to upload multiple images from ArrayList to Firebase Storage in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, upload

I have an ArrayList of path of images and I want to upload them to Firebase Storage in the same folder. For example I have 4 image path in my arraylist and I want to store it in the same folder named "places" which structured in firebase storage like this( gs://testexample.com/places/). Do I need to loop my arraylist to upload the image one by one? or are there any other ways to do it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Firebase developer here.
Right now, looping through the array is your only option, but we will consider alternative means to make this more efficient in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope there will be an easier way to do it in the future :)